# WPF generic.xaml could not find file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I have some custom converters for my wpf dialog.
All of sudden i get this message:

**`The Name "BoolToVisibilityInversConverter" is in the Namespace "clr-namespace:plans.SeqOpDialog.Converter;assembly=plans.SeqOpDialog" not available`**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"                    
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:plans.SeqOpDialog.Converter;assembly=plans.SeqOpDialog">

<conv:BoolToVisibilityInversConverter x:Key="btvInvConv"/>
<conv:TimeSpanConverter x:Key="timeConv"/>
<conv:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="btvConv"/>
<conv:BoolInversConverter x:Key="BoolInversConverter"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

A class as Example:

```
namespace plans.SeqOpDialog.Converter
{
    public class BoolToVisibilityInversConverter : IValueConverter
    {...
}}
```

I cleaned the project, restarted VS and i'm out of ideas what i could do

Comment: You have to ensure that this declaration `xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:plans.SeqOpDialog.Converter;assembly=plans.SeqOpDialog"` uses the correct namespace and assembly

Comment: namespace and assembly are correct

Comment: @AndreFritzsche: Does the project build and run?

Comment: @mm8 no i wasnt. But the solution was just to restart VS...

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss the Converter?

```
 xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:plans.SeqOpDialog.Converter;assembly=plans.SeqOpDialog.*Converter*">
```

Comment: no. The namespace is Converter and the assembly is without Converter.